# Get a large list of addresses from google maps api to help seed my database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Objective - gather a couple of fairly large (1000-2000) lists of addresses and coordinates for each address for a couple different regions like San Francisco, San Jose, New York City, etc.

Question - what's the best way to get a large list of addresses (any type - commercial, residential, etc.) for a region like San Francisco? Can I use google maps api??? It doesn't have to be exhaustive but I need a somewhat large list (~2000) to help me test my db querying. And the list doesn't have to be returned all at once, I can run multiple calls to the APi over time to get the data I need.

I would also need to get the coordinates for each address but I can do that in another call to google maps api if needed, but it would be nice if the coordinates were returned with the addresses.

I see there is a [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class that has a method getFromLocation that returns addresses given coordinates. But this is for Android, I need something for C# or javascript that I can use to get addresses to help me seed entity framework. Also from the documentation it looks like only a small number (1-5) of returned addresses are ok. I need to get addresses of say 2,000 addresses in a city like San Francisco and then I need to run it through google maps again to get the coordinates for each address.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

Comment: This may be against the Terms of Service for the Google Maps API ([https://developers.google.com/maps/terms][1] - see 10.1.3b) depending on whether you are doing this for performance reasons, and intend to periodically refresh that data, or not.


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research on Google Maps I think I have an idea.

1. write script to use google maps radar search
2. use google map radar search to get 200 nearby coordinates of a geographic location I pass in.
3. take each coordinate returned and pass that to reverse geocoding (address lookup) to get the address.
4. do this a handful of times and bingo I have a large list of addresses and coordinates for each address for a specific region like SF, NY, Chicago, etc to seed my db with.

Any thoughts or opinions!?

Comment: Why not use OpenStreetMap and search for address tags?